# Global WHERE clause for items that are marked disabled

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

Recently I had to add a new column for a shop I've made, determining whether item should be available for sale or not.

Now the thing. Is it possible to do something like global `where` clause or I must to add it separately for each query, that relates to certain column (e.g. `Products`)? It would be really hard to correct every query and not miss anything.

Example query I use looks like this, but it's just a very basic one. Normally these `where` clasues are multiline, including `select`s from another tables.

```
DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
// ...

protected bool SomeFunction() {
// ...
    var Products = db.Products.
                       Where(k => k.Active == true).
                       OrderByDescending(k => k.Date);
// ...
}
```

Normally I would do

```
var Products = db.Products.Where(k => k.Active == true);
Products = Products.
               Where( ... ).
               Select( ... ).
               OrderBy( ... ).
                  ...
               Take( ... );
```

But there are mulptiple functions (`db` is common for every function in class), and I was thinking about writing the condition on the SQL server side, but I have no knowledge about that, sadly.

Comment: `.Where(k => k.Active == true);` => `.Where(k => k.Active);`

Comment: That's one of the main reasons why you usually refactor data access code into a common place, like a set of repositories for instance. So you know exactly where it lives instead of having your queries all over the place.

Comment: It does not sound as a good practice. I think a global "where clause" will introduce other problems for you in the future. You should review and update your queries manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to change your products implementation:

Old:

```
class DataBaseContext 
{ 
     //...
     public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

New:

```
class DataBaseContext
{
     //...
     public IQueryable<Product> Products
     {
         get
         {
             return this.Set<Product>().Where(pr => pr.IsActive == true);
         }
     }
}
```

However, this is not very robust and maintenance friendly, since you would have to do this for every type of item that can be activated. Also, you would need to create a second property of type DbSet called `AllProducts` and then vary between if you want to get active or allitems  by checking all the points where the query is used.

Alternatively, you could create a wrapper for your `DbContext`:

```
interface IMyContext {
    void SaveChanges();
    IQueryable<T> Set<T>() where T: class
    IQUeryable<T> GetActiveItems<T>() where T : SomeBaseClassWithActiveProperty
}

public class MyContext : IMyContext {
    DataBaseContext _underylingContext = new DataBaseContext();

    //... save changes implementation etc   

    public IQueryable<T> Set<T>() 
           where T : class 
    {
           return _underlyingContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetActiveItems<T>() 
           where T : SomeBaseClassWithActiveProperty
    {
          return this.Set<T>().Where(item => item.IsActive == true);
    }
}
```

then, when using it:

```
 MyContext context = new MyContext();

 var activeProducts = from p in context.GetActiveItems<Product>()
                      order p  by p.Date //... or whatever;


 var allProducts = from p in context.Set<Product>() //....
```

Either way, you should go by and check all calls to the Product DbSet and validate if you only need active items or all items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside the database with the following two steps:

(1) Rename your existing table to something else.

(2) Create a view with the name of the existing table:

```
create view <tablename> as
    select *
    from <newtablename>
    where <your condition is true>;
```

(You probably want to list all the column instead of using `*`.)

Now all queries will use the view instead of the base table.

By the way, when designing an API for a database, it is a good idea to have all access be through views.  This allows changes like this after the API is in place.